# What should I do to view php errors in App engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud

I created a project and deployed an app created php72 app engine. 
As I cannot run php72 apps locally I'm trying to develop the app by deploying the each change.

My issue is when there is an error in the cloud app it doesn't show the error to front end.
So how can I access the error log?
It just stop the script from there.

Even I use a try catch and echo the $e-getMessage(), it's same.

Can anyone help me with this?

Also I checked Stackdriver logging. But there is no error logged.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

App Engine logs errors and messages to Stackdriver. You will be able to see the output in the Google Cloud Console under StackDriver -> App Engine.

Comment: Actually I checked there.. but it's logging only info.. not errors.

Comment: errors, warnings, debug and info go to the same place. Perhaps you do not have an error. Edit your question and post your code.